# Only two panels and the Weifen Luo library

Tags: visual-studio, panel

I want to make only two panels like [Solution Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools) and toolbox (Visual Studio) in my application.

The problem is that I don't understand how it works in the Weifen library. How can I make two dockable panels?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you elaborate? What application?

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the following steps:**

- Add reference to the Docking library.
- Create two forms.
- For each form go to source view and extend them from the **DockContent** class.

  ```
  public partial class ToolWindow : DockContent
  {
       public ToolWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
  }
  ```
- Add a DockPanel control to your main form. This is where your tool windows will be docked.
- To show the tool windows here is the sample code

  ```
  ToolWindow myToolWindow = new ToolWindow();
  myToolWindow.Show(this.myDockPanel, DockState.DockLeftAutoHide); // Dock Left & Auto Hide
  ```